How to correctly replace a git submodule
I had to do a history rewrite of a git repository, that was a submodule to several other repositories.
I know this destroys history, and make it cumbersome to restore earlier points in time, but that is a different matter.
I would assume that I could do something along the lines of this, given that the rewritten repository is located at <new-url>:
git submodule deinit -f <path-to-submodule>
git submodule set-url -- <path-to-submodule> <new-url>
git submodule update --init <path-to-submodule>

But actually it gets the files from the original url.
Both .gitmodules and .git/config are updated with the new url.
Instead I have to do
git submodule deinit -f <path-to-submodule>
git submodule set-url -- <path-to-submodule> <new-url>
git clone <new-url> <path-to-submodule>

Is this a bug in Git, or am I misunderstanding how it should work?
Edit 2024-11-19:
It is indeed my use of git submodule deinit that causes the problem.
The right way would then be:
git submodule set-url -- <path-to-submodule> <new-url>
git submodule update --init --remote <path-to-submodule>

I added the --remote to get the latest commit, as my submodule is rewritten, and a search for the commit SHA linked by the parent repository doesn't exist anyway.
Edit 2024-11-20:
The sad thing about this is that when one user does this operation, the .gitmodules file is obviously updated, but the next user that pulls the repository from git (presuming he/she alreaduy has the repo on his/her workstation) will have to do the same.
Git does not automatically detect the change in .gitmodules and applies the change to .git/config.

When I do this it works as desired, it uses the new url.  Try tracing the command to see what it's doing, GIT_TRACE=1 git submodule update --init next time.

"…it gets the files from the original url." Why do you think Git gets files from the original URL and not from the local cache in git/modules/? BTW do you know every commit in the superproject (the parent repo) records the corresponding commits of its submodules so git submodule update --init <path-to-submodule> updates to the recorded commit, not to the latest commit of the submodule? Most probably you need git submodule update --init --remote <path-to-submodule>. See https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit-submodules%5D+%22update+--remote%22 about --remote.

@phd you are right, I don't know if it gets the files from original url or a cache hereof. And both would be wrong. I have applied bidirectinal tags between parent and sub repos, to be able to see whitch commits are relevant at any given time. The original commi SHAs are obviously lost in the rewrite

See my answer to your question on the Git mailing list

@philb thank you for your quick processing of my 'bug report'. I have edited the question accordingly.
